# Problem with parameter passing for stringtemplate

Tags: templates, antlr, antlr3, stringtemplate

Given this rules :

```
 defServ: 'service' path bodyServ? SEP ->Serv(....);

 path: t+=ID ('/' t+=ID)* ->path(...);
```

I ask, as you can pass the token list "t" to the templete "Serv"?

The simplest solution would be to put the production of pathServ in defServ, that is :

```
   defServ: 'service'  t+=ID ('/' t+=ID)* bodyServ? SEP ->Serv(a={$t}, ...);
```

a better solution?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Tanuzzo88 wrote:*
>
> *I ask, as you can pass the token list "t" to the templete "Serv"?*

Sure, try this:

```
defServ
  :  'service' path bodyServ? SEP -> Serv(a={$path.ids})
  ;

path returns [List ids]
  :  t+=ID ('/' t+=ID)* {$ids = $t;}
  ;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the only thing missing '$' in the action of the rule path... :-)

Comment: Doesn't `{$ids = $t;}` and `{ids = $t;}` both work? Not able to test it at the moment though... Changed it to `$...` to be sure. Thanks.